# Text-based browser chat examples

Tags: cross-browser, client-server, chat, livechat

Given the abundance of new technologies for web development, I wonder which ones of them are particularly suited for **quickly** developing a minimal multiuser text-based chat app across different browsers? Anything based on Java, Python, or Javascript is especially welcome.

More specifically, I am also interested in how these technologies handle the following scenarios:

1. Latency of communication: what happens when a message from the client browser to the server (or the vice versa) gets delayed (or even lost)?
2. Disconnection: what happens when a client disconnects? Can we resume the communication from the exact state when the disconnection happens, so that all previous messages are still in place when the disconnected client reconnects.

I am seeking links to examples of implementing such a chat app as well as suggestions/pointers to the above. Thanks!

Comment: if you break this up into multiple questions i think you will get more answers